# Rejoining range seek on nullable composite index?

Tags: sql-server, index

For the following schema and example data

```
CREATE TABLE T
  (
     A INT NULL,
     B INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
     C CHAR(8000) NULL,
     UNIQUE CLUSTERED (A, B)
  )

INSERT INTO T
            (A)
SELECT NULLIF(( ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID) - 1 ) / 1003 ), 0)
FROM   master..spt_values
```

An application is processing the rows from this table in clustered index order in 1,000 row chunks.

The first 1,000 rows are retrieved from the following query.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 *
FROM   T
ORDER  BY A, B
```

The final row of that set is below

```
+------+------+
|  A   |  B   |
+------+------+
| NULL | 1000 |
+------+------+
```

Is there any way to write a query that just seeks into that composite index key and then follows it along to retrieve the next chunk of 1000 rows?

```
/*Pseudo Syntax*/
SELECT TOP 1000 *
FROM   T
WHERE (A, B) is_ordered_after (@A, @B)
ORDER  BY A, B
```

The lowest number of reads I've managed to get so far is 1020 but the query seems far too convoluted. Is there a simpler way of equal or better efficiency? Perhaps one that manages to do it all in one range seek?

```
DECLARE @A INT = NULL, @B INT = 1000

;WITH UnProcessed
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   T
         WHERE  ( EXISTS(SELECT A
                         INTERSECT
                         SELECT @A)
                  AND B > @B )
         UNION ALL
         SELECT *
         FROM   T
         WHERE @A IS NULL AND A IS NOT NULL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT *
         FROM   T
         WHERE A > @A        
         )
SELECT TOP 1000 *
FROM   UnProcessed
ORDER  BY A,
          B
```

[image]

---

FWIW: If the column `A` is made `NOT NULL` and a sentinel value of `-1` is used instead the equivalent execution plan certainly *looks* simpler

[image]

But the single seek operator in the plan [still performs two seeks](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/02/16/when-is-a-seek-not-a-seek.aspx) rather than collapsing it into a single contiguous range and the logical reads are much the same so I'm suspecting that maybe this is pretty much as good as it will get?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> *Is there any way to write a query that just seeks into that composite index key and then follows it along to retrieve the next chunk of 1000 rows?*

A favourite solution of mine is to use an `API` cursor:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET STATISTICS IO ON;

DECLARE 
    @cur integer,
    -- FAST_FORWARD, AUTO_FETCH, AUTO_CLOSE, CHECK_ACCEPTED_TYPES, FAST_FORWARD_ACCEPTABLE
    @scrollopt integer = 16 | 8192 | 16384 | 32768 | 1048576,
    -- READ_ONLY, CHECK_ACCEPTED_OPTS, READ_ONLY_ACCEPTABLE
    @ccopt integer = 1 | 32768 | 65536, 
    @rowcount integer = 1000,
    @rc integer;

-- Open the cursor and return (up to) the first 1000 rows
EXECUTE @rc = sys.sp_cursoropen
    @cur OUTPUT,
    N'
    SELECT A, B, C
    FROM T
    ORDER BY A, B;
    ',
    @scrollopt OUTPUT,
    @ccopt OUTPUT,
    @rowcount OUTPUT;

IF @rc <> 16 -- FastForward cursor automatically closed
BEGIN
    -- Name the cursor so we can use CURSOR_STATUS
    EXECUTE sys.sp_cursoroption
        @cur, 
        2, 
        'MyCursorName';

    -- Until the cursor auto-closes
    WHILE CURSOR_STATUS('global', 'MyCursorName') = 1
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE sys.sp_cursorfetch
            @cur,
            2,
            0,
            1000;
    END;
END;

SET STATISTICS IO OFF;
```

The overall strategy is a single scan that **remembers its position** between calls. Using an `API` cursor means we can return a block of rows rather than one at a time as would be the case with a `T-SQL` cursor:

[image: Execution plans]

The `STATISTICS IO` output is:

```
Table 'T'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1011, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0
Table 'T'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1001, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0
Table 'T'. Scan count 1, logical reads 516, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0
```